# Amazon S3 TransferUtilityUploadRequest timeout not working

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am using `AWSSDK.S3 version 3.3.10.2`, AWSSDK.CORE version `3.3.17.6`.

I am trying to add a timeout to the `TransferUtility.Upload` function

I followed the documentation written here: `http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/retries-timeouts.html`

This is my code:

```
m_AmazonS3Config.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1); 
m_AmazonS3Config.ReadWriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1);
using (IAmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(m_AmazonS3Config))
{
    var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
    var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = key,
        InputStream = fileStream,
    };

    fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
}
```

I tried uploading a big file and the timeout doesn't hit, why is that?

Answer (score 0):

AWS v3 documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/retries-timeouts.html). You are using v3 but you are following v2 document.

Also you have set timeout as 1 millisecond. That will not be enough considering large file. Try setting large timeout.

```
var client =  new AmazonS3Client(
  new AmazonS3Config
  {
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),            // Default value is 100 seconds
    ReadWriteTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),   // Default value is 300 seconds
    MaxErrorRetry = 2                              // Default value is 4 retries
  });
```